# Reduce the size of a tikz quiver diagram

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

The following tikz quiver code appears too large when compiled in latex. Is there a way to reduce it?

Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}[cramped]
    &&&&&&&&&&& {v_7} \\
    \\
    &&&&&&&&&&& {v_1} \\
    \\
    &&&&&&&&&&& {v_4} \\
    \\
    &&&&&&&&&&& {v_{10}} \\
    \\
    &&&&&&&&& {v_{11}} &&&& {v_{12}} \\
    &&&&&& {v_5} &&&&&&&&&& {v_6} \\
    &&& {v_2} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& {v_3} \\
    {v_8} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& {v_9}
    \arrow[no head, from=7-12, to=9-10]
    \arrow[no head, from=7-12, to=9-14]
    \arrow[no head, from=9-10, to=9-14]
    \arrow[no head, from=5-12, to=10-7]
    \arrow[no head, from=5-12, to=10-17]
    \arrow[no head, from=10-7, to=10-17]
    \arrow[no head, from=3-12, to=11-4]
    \arrow[no head, from=3-12, to=11-20]
    \arrow[no head, from=11-4, to=11-20]
    \arrow[no head, from=1-12, to=12-23]
    \arrow[no head, from=1-12, to=12-1]
    \arrow[no head, from=12-1, to=12-23]
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please complete your code? These steps may help you: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 . A screenshot may also help. Thank you

Comment: There are a lot of empty matrix entries in your diagram. Do you need to separate your nodes with all of those `&`'s?

Comment: I seems like you want to draw a lot of "concentric" triangles. How about using tikz to draw equilateral triangles instead of isosceles ones?

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cramped, sep=tiny]
&&&&&&&&&&& {v_7} \\
\\
&&&&&&&&&&& {v_1} \\
\\
&&&&&&&&&&& {v_4} \\
\\
&&&&&&&&&&& {v_{10}} \\
\\
&&&&&&&&& {v_{11}} &&&& {v_{12}} \\
&&&&&& {v_5} &&&&&&&&&& {v_6} \\
&&& {v_2} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& {v_3} \\
{v_8} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& {v_9}
\arrow[no head, from=7-12, to=9-10]
\arrow[no head, from=7-12, to=9-14]
\arrow[no head, from=9-10, to=9-14]
\arrow[no head, from=5-12, to=10-7]
\arrow[no head, from=5-12, to=10-17]
\arrow[no head, from=10-7, to=10-17]
\arrow[no head, from=3-12, to=11-4]
\arrow[no head, from=3-12, to=11-20]
\arrow[no head, from=11-4, to=11-20]
\arrow[no head, from=1-12, to=12-23]
\arrow[no head, from=1-12, to=12-1]
\arrow[no head, from=12-1, to=12-23]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: Triangular cumulative diagram]

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it.

[image: result]

The code at the end shows just one triangle, which would work, if you'd use it in a `tikzpicture` environment:

```
% ~~~ just one triangle ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw ( 90:1) node[txt]{$v_1$} -- 
          (200:2) node[txt]{$v_2$} -- 
          (340:2) node[txt]{$v_3$} -- cycle;
```

- use polar coordinates
- draw from (90:1) to (200:2) to (340:2) and close and end (`;`) this path
- put a `node` each time you are at the next position (watch the missing `\`)
- use a style for this node, which just fills some white color
- place some text, here in math mode `$ .. $`

Drawing a second one AND thinking in terms of refactoring, using a TeX-macro seems reasonable:

- `Tikz` tends to favor `\def` over `\newcommand`, certainly for a reason
- to keep things simple enough, I just pass the vertical length and 3 indices (this could certainly be refined further)
- which abstracts the same triangle into:

```
\def\triag#1#2#3#4{% y-length, 3 indices
    \draw ( 90:#1  ) node[txt]{$v_{#2}$} -- %
          (200:2*#1) node[txt]{$v_{#3}$} -- %
          (340:2*#1) node[txt]{$v_{#4}$} -- cycle;}%
```

Finally, just make as many calls to these triangles as you like inside a `tikzpicture` environment, which expands into a series of said `\draw ... ;` paths:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\def\triag#1#2#3#4{% y-length, 3 indices
    \draw ( 90:#1  ) node[txt]{$v_{#2}$} -- %
          (200:2*#1) node[txt]{$v_{#3}$} -- %
          (340:2*#1) node[txt]{$v_{#4}$} -- cycle;}%

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    txt/.style={fill=white},
 ]
    \triag{.5}{10}{11}{12}
    \triag{1  }{4}{5}{6}
    \triag{1.5}{1}{2}{3}
    \triag{2  }{7}{8}{9}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

% ~~~ just one triangle ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%   \draw ( 90:1) node[txt]{$v_1$} -- 
%         (200:2) node[txt]{$v_2$} -- 
%         (340:2) node[txt]{$v_3$} -- cycle;

% ~~~ later refactored using a TeX macro \triag ~~~
```